# How to maintain ActiveMQ connection open?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, nms

I'm using Apache ActiveMQ to integrate my app to a custom service. I need to make this run always, not one time like it's right now. 
The code below works, but only for one message, I need to maintain the connection active in order to receive all the messages.

```
using (var connection = (Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection)factory.CreateConnection())
{
   connection.UserName = Username;
   connection.Password = Password;

   using (var session = connection.CreateSession())
   {
        IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://" + Queue);

        using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination))
        //using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateDurableConsumer(new ActiveMQTopic(Queue), "fpapp", null, false))
        {
            consumer.Listener += ConsumerOnListener;
            connection.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research and found out I should create a durable consumer, and that's what I tried  (commented line). But it doesn't work, it says network connections can't subscribe to topics.

Any ideas?

PS: I'm completely new to ActiveMQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take the connection object out of using block. It will do. 
In C# API normal connection is durable, in STOMP one have to set heartbeat.

Comment: msaero, what is wrong with this code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632265/connection-closes-after-few-seconds-when-connecting-to-activemq-set-up-on-aws