# Connection closes after few seconds when connecting to ActiveMQ set up on AWS

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, nms

I am connecting to Apache Active MQ which is hosted on AWS to integrate my app to a custom service. I need to keep this running always, not one time like it's right now. The code below works, but only for one message, I need to maintain the connection active all the time listening in order to receive all the messages.
Here is the code.

```
    using Apache.NMS;
    using Apache.NMS.Util;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApacheMQAsync
{
    class Program
    {

        protected static ITextMessage message = null;


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Uri connecturi = new Uri("URL:61617");

            Console.WriteLine("About to connect to " + connecturi);

            // NOTE: ensure the nmsprovider-activemq.config file exists in the executable folder.
            IConnectionFactory factory = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory(connecturi);

            IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection("username", "password");

            ISession session = connection.CreateSession();
            IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://FOO.BAR");

            Console.WriteLine("Using destination: " + destination);

            // Create a consumer and producer
            IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);

            consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);
            connection.Start();
            // Wait for the message


            if (message == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No message received!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received message with ID:   " + message.NMSMessageId);
                Console.WriteLine("Received message with text: " + message.Text);
            }
        }

        protected static void OnMessage(IMessage receivedMsg)
        {
            message = receivedMsg as ITextMessage;
            message.Acknowledge();

        }
    }
}
```

On the console it displays following
No message received!
and after few seconds the console exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real magic there, you need to do something to keep your application running such as pausing on console input or looping on a sleep or other wait type call and then checking something to see if your application should continue.  The JMS client isn't guaranteed to keep your application open and running and you should never rely on it to.

Comment: Thanks Tim, do you mean to put it in a loop, like while(true)?

Comment: Do whatever works for your application and business logic